# Insert into table with foreign key using Hibernate DAO method

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys

Here I'm trying to insert a row to a table which has a foreign key Using hibernate. But i get the following exception : "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.xxx.model.Employee". How can i solve this issue? Following is my code :

Employee.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Employee {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "emp_name")
private String emp_name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
private Department department;

@Column(name = "emp_id")
private String emp_id;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmp_name() {
    return floor_name;
}

public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
    this.emp_name = emp_name;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public String getEmp_id() {
    return emp_id;
}

public void setEmp_id(String emp_id) {
    this.emp_id = emp_id;
}

}
```

Department.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Department {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "dept_name")
    private String dept_name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDept_name() {
        return dept_name;
    }

    public void setDept_name(String dept_name) {
        this.dept_name = dept_name;
    }
  }
```

To add new employee :

```
        Department department = null;
        department = departmentService.getDepartmentById(id);

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmp_name(emp_name);
        employee.setEmp_id(emp_id);
        employee.setDepartment(department);
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
```

In EmployeeDaoImpl :

```
@Override
public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(employee);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return false;
}
```

In DepartmentDaoImpl :

```
@Override
public Building getDepartmentById(long id) throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Department department = (Department) session.load(Department.class, new Long(id));
    tx = session.getTransaction();
    session.beginTransaction();
    tx.commit();
    return department;
}
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.xxx.model.Employee</value>
                <value>com.xxx.model.Department</value>
            </list>

        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="employeeDao" class="edu.am.amrita.trackapi.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="employeeService" class="edu.am.amrita.trackapi.services.EmployeeServiceImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="departmentDao" class="edu.am.amrita.trackapi.dao.DepartmentDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="departmentService" class="edu.am.amrita.trackapi.services.DepartmentServiceImpl"></bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your hibernate entities are being scanned. You can either configure them into hibernate.cfg.xml or through

```
packagesToScan
```

attribute of SessionFactory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have updated my question with  config xml file content, please check if it is correct or not?

Comment: the issue was class name was missing in sessionFactory. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nayana_Das, it is always encouraged to use packagesToScan over annotatedClasses and listing down all the entities. This will reduce your configuration file burden and you might need not to look the config file again while defining new entities. I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

In Department pojo, Employee mapping should be there like shown below with setter and getters

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Employee  emp;
```

Comment: Do we have to give join column for Department class too? Bcoz i have already given join column in Employee class such as @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="department_id") private Department department;

Comment: This is required if you want to do bidirectional mapping. Entities can be recognized with unidirectional mapping.